# Given a string as input,write a python program to print ticket id of all passengers

Tags: python

input format=`src:destination:mob_no`
output = First two characters of src followed by last two characters of destination followed by sum of numbers at even indices (including zero)
plus the sequence of passengers starting with 1.

e.g:Input is

```
Paris:Delhi:9945672345,Berlin:Brussels:9456723456
```

and output should be

```
Pahi251,Bels292
```

Code used

```py
a="Paris:Delhi:9945672345","Berlin:Brussels:9456723456"
c=a[0][0:2]
d=a[0][9:11]
mob_no=a[0][12:]

i=0
sum=0
while(i<len(mob_no)):
    if i%2==0:
        e=mob_no[i]
        sum=sum+int(e)
    i=i+1

ticket =str(c)+str(d)+str(sum)+str(1) 

print(ticket)
```

Comment: What you have done so far? Can share it here?

Comment: Updated my code,it is giving me Pahi251 but i am not able to find a way to get output as Pahi251,Bels292.I tried for first index value and it is giving correct result but for second index value i need help

Comment: The first line of code seems wrong; your input should be a single string.

Comment: Btw, `i==0 or i%2==0` can be simplified to `i%2==0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment of `a` seems wrong. Your question states that the input is a string, not a list of strings.

Your code attempts to fetch substrings at fixed offsets, but of course, your input is not fixed-length; each city could have a different length than every other city.  Instead, you want to simply `split` on the delimiter character, `":"`.

You can use `enumerate` to loop over the list with an index variable, and `range` to loop over uneven indices in the mobile phone number.

```py
a = "Paris:Delhi:9945672345,Berlin:Brussels:9456723456"

tickets = []

for idx, leg in enumerate(a.split(","), 1):
    src, dest, mob = leg.split(":")
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(mob), 2):
        sum += int(mob[i])
    tickets.append("%s%s%i%i" % (src[0:2], dest[-2:], sum, idx))

print(tickets)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/YFC9hB

Going forward, probably try to bite off a smaller piece at a time, and figure out which part of the code isn't doing what you hope. Sprinkle with `print` statements so Python tells you the value of each variable at every interesting point in the program. Then compare with what you expect, and probably google before asking a question with a [minimum reproducible example](/help/mre).